# get value of element in xml-file using JDOM

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, jdom, jdom-2

I have xml-file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<products xmlns="http://www.myapp.com/shop" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.myapp.com/shop shop.xsd">
    <category name="yyy">
        <subcategory name="yyy1">
            <goods name="yyy11">                
                <model>ferrari</model>              
            </goods>
        </subcategory>
    </category>
</products>
```

i try to get value of element `<model>` as

```
SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder();
File xmlProductFile = new File("shop.xml");
Document document = builder.build(xmlProductFile);
Element rootNode = document.getRootElement();       

String category = rootNode.getChild("model").getText();
```

But I get empty value

Comment: Hi Ray, one issue that's probably confusing you is the Namespace on the element. You will need to supply a Namespace instance to all your JDOM methods if you want to be able to select the Elements. For example, rootNode.getChild("category") will return nothing, but rootNode.getChild("category", Namespace.getNamespace("http://www.myapp.com/shop")) will return the category Element

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You *must* have to use `getDescendants(Filter<F>)` method to select a specific `Element`

```
Element root = document.getRootElement();
ElementFilter filter = new org.jdom2.filter.ElementFilter("model");
for(Element c : root.getDescendants(filter)) {
    System.out.println(c.getTextNormalize());
}
```